# Generating a loop from multiple inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to generate a list of 1000 houses based on the given inputs of 2 houses i.e `House_1=[143.5689855, -38.328956999999996]` and `House_2=[143.5692555, -38.328993]`. The difference of these houses will be added to next subsequent houses as shown in below script.

```
from arcgis.geocoding import reverse_geocode
import pprint

House_1=[143.5689855, -38.328956999999996]
House_2=[143.5692555, -38.328993]


latitude_diff = House_2[0] - House_1[0]
longitude_diff= House_2[1] - House_1[1]



House_3=[House_2[0]+latitude_diff ,House_2[1]+longitude_diff]
pprint.pprint(House_3)

House_4=[House_3[0]+latitude_diff ,House_3[1]+longitude_diff]
pprint.pprint(House_4)

House_5=[House_4[0]+latitude_diff ,House_4[1]+longitude_diff]
pprint.pprint(House_5)
.
.
.
.
.
House_1000=[House_999[0]+latitude_diff ,House_999[1]+longitude_diff]
pprint.pprint(House_1000)
```

- As I have used a manual process to generate a list of 3 houses i.e `House_3, House_4, House_5`.How to generate a loop that will automatically iterate for 1000 houses and output the required results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
Houses = [0]*(1000)
Houses[0], Houses[1] = [143.5689855, -38.328956999999996], [143.5692555, -38.328993]
for i in range(2, 1000):
    latitude_diff = Houses[i-1][0] - Houses[i-2][0]
    longitude_diff= Houses[i-1][1] - Houses[i-2][1]
    temp = [Houses[i-1][0]+latitude_diff, Houses[i-1][1]+longitude_diff]

    Houses[i] = temp
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe go through the Python tutorial at least once? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function

Answer (score 1):

So house_3 is latitude is `House_2[0]+1* latitude_diff` and house_4 latitude is `House_2[0] + 2 * latitude_diff`

So you can do a list comprehension -

```
houses = [House_1, House_2]
for i in range(1, num_houses):
    curr_house = [House_2[0] + i* latitude_diff, House_2[1] + i* longitude_diff]
    pprint.pprint(curr_house)
    houses.append(curr_house)
```